# Is there "Hover" option to Button in libgdx?

Tags: android, libgdx, game-engine, scene2d

I'm new to libgdx, I see in the constructor of `Button` there is a parameter for the button texture, and a texture for when it is pressed.. 
Here is the documentation : 
[Scene2d.ui#Button](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Button.html)

Is it possible to add "Hover" option to a button ?( a 3rd texture that appears when the mouse hovers over the button).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the constructor taking a `ButtonStyle`. You will be able to set all of the drawables on that style. The `over` and `checkedOver` fields correspond to hover.